How to get JSON output from gemini-1.5-pro-001 using curl
How can I retrieve data in JSON format from the Gemini 1.5 API using curl?
The code below works correctly:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'      
-H "x-goog-api-key: ${API_KEY}"      
-d '{"contents":[
            {"role": "user",
              "parts":[{"text": "Give me five subcategories of jazz?"}]}]}'      
"https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1/models/gemini-pro:generateContent"

But when I try to add:
,"generation_config": {"response_mime_type": "application/json"}}

Giving:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H "x-goog-api-key: ${API_KEY}" 
-d '{"contents":[
            {"role": "user",
              "parts":[{"text": "Give me five subcategories of jazz?"}]},"generation_config": {"response_mime_type": "application/json"},]'      
"https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent"

I receive this error response:
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"response_mime_type\" at 'generation_config': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "generation_config",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"response_mime_type\" at 'generation_config': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

I've tried with several different models (e.g. gemini-1.5-pro-latest) always with the same result.

Try this.
curl https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent?key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -X POST \
    -d '{
        "contents": [{
            "parts":[
                {"text": "Write a story about a magic backpack."}
            ]
        }],
        "safetySettings": [
            {
                "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT",
                "threshold": "BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH"
            }
        ],
        "generationConfig": {
            "stopSequences": [
                "Title"
            ],
            "temperature": 1.0,
            "maxOutputTokens": 800,
            "topP": 0.8,
            "topK": 10,
            "responseMimeType": "application/json"
        }
    }'  2> /dev/null | grep "text"


The issue was simply that I had missed the v1beta part of the url which is required for generating JSON output.

Modification points:

In the current stage, in order to use "response_mime_type": "application/json", it is required to use v1beta instead of v1.

Also, in your showing curl command, the request body is as follows. This request body is not enclosed by }. And, generation_config is required to be moved from contents property.
{
   "contents":[
      {
         "role":"user",
         "parts":[{"text":"Give me five subcategories of jazz?"}]
      },
      "generation_config":{"response_mime_type":"application/json"}
   ]


The modified request body is as follows.
{
   "contents":[
      {
         "role":"user",
         "parts":[{"text":"Give me five subcategories of jazz?"}]
      }
   ],
   "generation_config":{"response_mime_type":"application/json"}
}





When these points are reflected in your curl command, they become as follows:
Modified curl command:
curl \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H "x-goog-api-key: ${API_KEY}" \
-d '{"contents":[{"role":"user","parts":[{"text":"Give me five subcategories of jazz?"}]}],"generation_config":{"response_mime_type":"application/json"}}' \
"https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent"

When this curl command is run, the following result is obtained.
{
  "candidates": [
    {
      "content": {
        "parts": [
          {
            "text": "[\"Bebop\", \"Cool Jazz\", \"Modal Jazz\", \"Fusion Jazz\", \"Latin Jazz\"]\n"
          }
        ],
        "role": "model"
      },
      "finishReason": "STOP",
      "index": 0,
      "safetyRatings": [
        {
          "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT",
          "probability": "NEGLIGIBLE"
        },
        {
          "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH",
          "probability": "NEGLIGIBLE"
        },
        {
          "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT",
          "probability": "NEGLIGIBLE"
        },
        {
          "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT",
          "probability": "NEGLIGIBLE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "usageMetadata": {
    "promptTokenCount": 9,
    "candidatesTokenCount": 20,
    "totalTokenCount": 29
  }
}

Note:

As additional information, the API key can also be used as the query parameter instead of the request header like https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent?key=${apiKey}.

Reference:

Generating content with JSON mode

